# getpassword error: Inappropriate ioctl for device vnc error

Tags: linux, centos-6.6, tigervnc

I installed tigervnc-server package in server.

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa tigervnc
tigervnc-1.1.0-16.el6.x86_64
```

Created a vnc user and created vncpasswd also for that user.

```
[root@localhost ~]# useradd vnc
[root@localhost ~]# vncpasswd vnc
Password:
Verify:
[root@localhost ~]#
```

In /etc/sysconfig/vncserver I changed these 2 lines

```
VNCSERVERS="2:vnc"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600"
```

While starting service it's giving this error.

```
[root@localhost ~]# service vncserver start
Starting VNC server: 2:vnc 
You will require a password to access your desktops.

getpassword error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Password:                                                  [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 12):

This error occurs most often because the configured user doesn't have a vncpasswd set. To fix this, as the user simply execute 'vncpasswd' and follow the prompts. It's just like passwd so you should already be familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same problem.  The issue for me was that I did not "su" to the user and re-type the passwords as shown in Step 3 of the following link.

Follow the instructions on the link below verbatim and you should be good to go.

http://tecadmin.net/setup-vnc-server-on-centos-redhat-and-fedora/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The user is also logged in as root, so `su` should be unnecessary.  If it *is* still necessary then you should explain why.