# vncserver service fails to start

Tags: vnc, vncserver

Trying to [setup](https://www.tecmint.com/install-and-configure-vnc-server-in-centos-7/#attachment_27180) VNCServer for accessing a CentOS7 machine via Windows Remote Desktop and getting errors starting the VNC service:

```bsh
[root@HW006 ~]# systemctl start vncserver@:1
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@HW006 ~]# journalctl -xe
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit vncserver@:1.service has begun starting up.
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local systemd[1]: Started Session c6 of user testuser001.
-- Subject: Unit session-c6.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-c6.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local runuser[54228]: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session opened for us
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local runuser[54228]: You will require a password to access your desktop
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local runuser[54228]: getpassword error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local runuser[54228]: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session closed for us
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: control process exited, code=exi
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local runuser[54228]: Password:
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
-- Subject: Unit vncserver@:1.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit vncserver@:1.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state.
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service failed.
Sep 13 14:46:14 HW006.co.local polkitd[18280]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process
lines 1168-1196/1196 (END)
```

Not sure what to make of this. Anyone with more experience know what could be going on here or what further debugging output would be useful here (not very experienced with networking stuff)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getpassword error: Inappropriate ioctl for device vnc error](https://superuser.com/questions/901727/getpassword-error-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-vnc-error)

Comment: Looking further info the error output, lead me to https://superuser.com/a/1072195/869740. Following the article linked in the question, did not realize that the `vncpasswd` command had to be run as the user named in the `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@\:1.service` file. Marking this as duplicate.